# Remove header logo CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, hide

Good evening, i have one question, how can i hide this logo  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjfYD.jpg)

in my website with a custom css?

this is my code, i think the class of my logo is sticky-logo, itried so much but i can't hide it. please help me.

```html
<body class="page-template page-template-page-templates page-template-landing-page page-template-page-templateslanding-page-php page page-id-10270 logged-in  siteorigin-panels" id="thim-body">
  <div id="wrapper-container" class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="content-pusher " style="padding-top: 149px;">
      <header id="masthead" class="site-header affix-top sticky-header header_default header_v1">
        <div id="toolbar" class="toolbar">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
                  <div class="textwidget">
                    <div class="thim-have-any-question"> Hai delle domande?
                      <div class="mobile"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span class="value">045 581062</span></div>
                      <div class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:segreteria@corsiverona.it">segreteria@corsiverona.it</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </aside>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="navigation col-sm-12">
              <div class="tm-table">
                <div class="width-logo table-cell sm-logo">
                  <a href="https://www.corsiverona.it/" title="CorsiVerona - Un nuovo sito professionale marcato Corsi Verona" rel="home" class="no-sticky-logo"><img src="https://www.corsiverona.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Corsi-verona_logoArancio-Nero2.jpg" alt="CorsiVerona" width="300" height="59"></a>
                  <a href="https://www.corsiverona.it/" title="CorsiVerona - Un nuovo sito professionale marcato Corsi Verona"
                    rel="home" class="sticky-logo"> <img src="https://www.corsiverona.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Corsi-verona_logoArancio-Nero2.jpg" alt="CorsiVerona" width="300" height="59">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can hide your logo like this:

```
.sm-logo {
  display: none;
}
```

Try the snippet below:

```css
.sm-logo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="page-template page-template-page-templates page-template-landing-page page-template-page-templateslanding-page-php page page-id-10270 logged-in  siteorigin-panels" id="thim-body">
  <div id="wrapper-container" class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="content-pusher " style="padding-top: 149px;">
      <header id="masthead" class="site-header affix-top sticky-header header_default header_v1">
        <div id="toolbar" class="toolbar">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
                  <div class="textwidget">
                    <div class="thim-have-any-question"> Hai delle domande?
                      <div class="mobile"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span class="value">045 581062</span></div>
                      <div class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:segreteria@corsiverona.it">segreteria@corsiverona.it</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </aside>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="navigation col-sm-12">
            <div class="tm-table">
              <div class="width-logo table-cell sm-logo">
                <a href="https://www.corsiverona.it/" title="CorsiVerona - Un nuovo sito professionale marcato Corsi Verona" rel="home" class="no-sticky-logo"><img src="https://www.corsiverona.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Corsi-verona_logoArancio-Nero2.jpg" alt="CorsiVerona" width="300" height="59"></a>
                <a href="https://www.corsiverona.it/" title="CorsiVerona - Un nuovo sito professionale marcato Corsi Verona" rel="home" class="sticky-logo"> <img src="https://www.corsiverona.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Corsi-verona_logoArancio-Nero2.jpg" alt="CorsiVerona" width="300" height="59"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```